# window.close causes spinning beach ball on safari

Tags: javascript, safari

I have a page with a button that opens a child page with a form on it.  The child page has a Cancel button that does window.close on itself. But after the window closes, I get the safari (12.02) spinning beach ball.  Seems to go away after I do some other stuff.  Chrome and Firefox don't seem to have a problem.  I tried watching the developr tool timeline and there's a bunch of js action going on but I can't figure out what it is.

tried adding return false; and fooling around with window names, but nothing seems to help.  Also using slim framework, but don't think that's relevant. Have jquery, but not using it on this action.

### On parent page:

```
<script>  
function openMiniAsset(id_id){
   var id = document.getElementById(id_id).value;
   // alert ('id' +id + "params: " + params );
    var newin = window.open('/asset_mini/'+id,'asset_mini');
    return false;
}
</script>
...
 <button type='button' 
 onClick= "openMiniAsset('edit_asset_id');return false;">
 Open</button>
```

### On child page:

```
<button type='button' onClick="self.close();return false;">
Cancel</button>
```

Comment: What is `self`?

Comment: I started with window.close and then tried sel.close but it didn’t make any difference. Some script is clearly not completing cleanly. This seems so simple I can’t see what the bug is.

Comment: Self would be the button object which doesn’t make sense. But window.close does the same thing. Window closes, then in about 3 seconds the beachbll starts spinning.

Comment: There's no standard `self` variable in JavaScript, maybe you meant `this.close()`? But as you say, `this` is the button, not the window.

Comment: I just tried this, I get the spinning beach ball, but Safari isn't really hung. If I click on something it works, and the beach ball goes away. http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/rot6nsxe/3/

Comment: Seems like a Safari bug to me.

Answer (score 1):

It can be avoided by making the close window an asynchronous process.

```
    setTimeout(function() {
        window.open('about:blank', '_self').close();
    }, 100);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is apparently a bug in safari.  I finally ended up testing two simple pages: one has nothing on it except a window.open button to the second, and the second has a single button that's window.close().  I still get the spinning beach ball.  Thanks Barmar for looking into it.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
onClick="self.close();return false;"
```

with

```
onClick="setTimeout(self.close,100);return false;"
```

worked for me.